# Deduplicate Text File with Awk but keep the lines with the non-empty field

Tags: awk

I am trying to deduplicate the rows of a text file with Awk but prefer to keep duplicated lines with the non-empty field "f4" (unless all those dup'ed lines have a blank field "f4").

Input_File

```
f1|f2|f3|f4|f5
aa|bb|cc||ee
aa|bb|cc|dd|ee
aa|bb|cc|dd|ee
aa|bb|cc||ee
aaa|qq|ccc||eee
aaa|qq|ccc|zz|eee
aaa|qq|ccc|zz|eee
aaa|qq|ccc||eee
aaa|qq|ccc||eee
new|test|ccc||eee
new|test|ccc||eee
```

Output Needed

```
f2|f4
bb|dd
qq|zz
test|
```

Code tried (not working - getting wrong output):

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{ if ( !seen[$2, $3]++ ) print $2, $4 } '   Input_File
```

Wrong Output

```
f2|f4
bb|
qq|
test|
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why `test|` is there in your sample output? its 4th field is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed the question so adding new answer now. This will check if a 2nd field has 4th field or not, if it has it will print its unique value or if all of its occurrence are NOT having any 4th field then empty field will be printed.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR==NR{
  if(!a[$2]){
    a[$2]=$4
  }
  next
}
($2 in a) && $4==a[$2]{
  print $2,$4
  delete a[$2]
}'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
f2|f4
bb|dd
qq|zz
test|
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $2 && $4{print $2,$4}' Input_file
```

Above will check field 2nd and 4th if they are both are NON-empty then it will print the lines, in case you want to check only 4th field then change above to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $4{print $2,$4}' Input_file
```

If you want to remove duplicates and check 4th column's existence use following then.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $4 && !a[$4]++{print $2,$4}' Input_file
```

Comment: @Steve_A, could you please check my EDIT answer and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     $4 {print $2,$4}' file
```

To add the dedup logic:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
     $4 && seen[$2]++<1 {print $2,$4}' file
```

Comment: Your edit makes this a fundamentally different question. Now the entire file needs to be read and dealt with rather than line by line.

Comment: @Steve_A, it is always recommended to post your requirements in single shot itself, adding conditions later is not good as it may waste our efforts.